# Android : value null at 0 of type org.json.jsonobject$1 cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: android, json, android-json

I'am fetching the data from the server and storing in my android application. I'am getting the JSONArray name as "project_data" and am having list of JSONObjects in the array. Am iterating the list of JSONObject based on the length of JSONArray.

**This is the JSON data where am getting from the server**

```
"project_data": [
    null,
    null,
    {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "JOHN",
        "short_name": "JH",          
    }
]
```

**This is the error what am facing**

```
value null at 0 of type org.json.jsonobject$1 cannot be converted to jsonobject
```

**This is my code**

```
JSONArray projectData=job.getJSONArray("project_data");
for(int i=0;i<projectData.length();i++)
        {               
          JSONObject proj=projectData.getJSONObject(i);
          Log.i("projectdetails",proj.toString());
          pro = Project.getProject(getValue(proj,"id"));
          if(pro==null)
              pro=new Project();
          pro.p_id = getValue(proj,"id");
          pro.name = getValue(proj,"name");
          pro.short_name = getValue(proj,"short_name");
          pro.save();
        }
```

I'am facing the error in this line.
**JSONObject proj=projectData.getJSONObject(i);**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well server should not give you null data but for particular if you really want to get the result you may try removing for loop then

```
JSONObject proj=projectData.getJSONObject(2);//index of your json object in projectData array, 0,1 are null so you are getting that error
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Server should not return null but if it happens in some situation we have to handle from the android part. My one more doubt is if i get this null values in shuffle manner then how can i handle this? Right now I'am not facing this situation. But in future i should handle this problem. Could you give me an idea?

Comment: you can always check if (jsonObject != null)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
 Object obj = jArray.get(i);
 if (obj != null && !obj.toString().equals("null")) {
    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //Make parse here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change data from server ? You must get from PHP server data like this

```
{"project_data": [{"id": "14","name": "JOHN","short_name": "JH" }]}
```

Then decoding JSON object is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtView;
TextView txtView1;
int i=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);

    //String job = "'project_data': [null,null,{'id': '14','name': 'JOHN','short_name': 'JH', }]"; //bad data
    String job = "{'project_data': [{'id': '14','name': 'JOHN','short_name': 'JH' }]}"; 




    txtView.setText(job);

    try{


        String s =" " ;
        JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(job);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("project_data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            s= s+   "name: " + explrObject.getString("name")+"\n" +
              "short_name: "+ explrObject.getString("short_name") +"\n";


        }


        txtView1.setText(s);
    }catch(Exception e){

        txtView.setText( "error 3 "+i+" "+ e.toString());
    }



}


}
```